# Setting time limit php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set time limit in reservation system. Such that Users must
have the ability to remove their bookings, but not before the lapse of 1 minute away from the time when the booking has been entered

```
 <?php 
 require_once 'connection.php';


if(isset($_SESSION['book'])){

if (isset($_SESSION['book_time'])){
    if (time()-$_SESSION['book_time']>= 60){

        if (isset($_POST['delete'])){       

$machineID = $_POST['machine_id'];
$starttime = $_POST['start_time'];

$qry = "DELETE FROM bookings where machine_id = '$machineID' AND start_time = '$starttime'";

$result =  mysql_query($qry,$conn);
if ($result){

    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
        $message[] = 'Booking Deleted form DB';
    }
  }

    }
}
 }
  }
?>
```

but it couldn't remove even after 1 min with this script....what could be possible problem

Comment: That's very nice. Is there no question?

Comment: Please specify what the problem is, what behavior you expect and which behavior you actually get.

Comment: There's no question he just wanted to congratulate oneself

Comment: Obligatory comment: Please filter your variables and/or using parameter binding to avoid sql injections.

Comment: he may want $starttime - 60 // 1min

Comment: Sorry, I forget the question...now up there

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

- $_SESSION['book'] or $_SESSION['book_time'] or $_POST['delete'] is NULL
- $machineID contains not exists ID
- $starttime contains wrong time or time in wrong format

Try to dump this variables. If they are ok try to run query manualy.